# Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Can I start building Windows 10 apps on the preview version with Visual Studio 2015 preview?  Or at least start tinkering and testing?

Comment: VS2015 doesn't have a Go Live license yet.  You can build, tinker and test all you want, Microsoft loves getting feedback from unpaid beta testers.

Comment: VS 2015 Technical Preview includes the Windows 8.1 SDK, but not the Windows 10 SDK.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. The SO FAQ mentions software tools exclusively used by programmers, which Visual Studio definitely is. This has nothing to do with "general" computing and would be off topic for Super User.

Answer (score 5):

Update 23 March:
[Visual Studio Tools for Windows 10 Technical Preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2015/03/23/visual-studio-tools-for-windows-10-technical-preview.aspx) is now available and will allow Windows Insiders to build Windows 10 apps with Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 and test drive the new [Windows 10 Technical Preview tools](http://dev.windows.com/en-US/windows-10-developer-preview-tools).

====================

Windows 10 specific development has not yet been announced, but the existing Universal Windows apps are the foundation to start on. You can tinker and test Windows Universal apps with Visual Studio 2015 (or 2013) and run them on the Windows 10 previews.

See [Universal Windows apps get better with Windows 10](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/09/30/universal-windows-apps-get-better-with-windows-10/) and the [Get Started](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted) section at http://dev.windows.com

Answer (score 0):

Just updating links to **new versions** of everything released during *Build 2015* conference a few days ago:

- [Download Windows 10 **Insider Preview** ISO](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-iso) (previous version was *Technical Preview*)
- [Visual Studio 2015 **RC** Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx) (previous version was *CTP 6*)

This time VS2015 installation also includes tools for Windows 10 development so no need in other separate downloads. Also you may really go with free *Community Edition* - it also fully support developing for Windows 10.

Note, that you could install VS2015RC not only on Windows 10 (Insider Preview), but also on Windows 8.1 or Windows 7 machine and **start developing** for Windows 10 using emulators that comes with VS2015RC installation **right now**, so that when Windows 10 *and* VS2015 will be released you could just build the release of your app with RTM tools and **publish to Store** what will be available along with Windows 10 release **later this year**.