# Does Visual Studio 2015 works with Windows 10?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am trying to install Visual Studio Professional 2015 on windows 10 but it just hangs every time. It starts correctly but hangs in the middle. See the screenshot. 
Note: I've seen this question [Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077977/windows-10-and-visual-studio-2015) and the Visual Studio page but didn't help it. [image]
Stopping shows because I cancelled it after 10 hours.

Comment: May I know the reason for down voting it?

Comment: This VS release is dedicated to Windows 10 so your question title is ridiculous. The installation might fail for various reasons but you should get started from installation log which many similar posts can guide you.

Comment: I'm switching to C# from another language. So if someone doesn't know something and ask a question, you'll say that its ridiculous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to list what you've attempted to do / tried but here's my list, start from top to bottom.

1. The file may be blocked as Win10 does this for me all the time,
   right click on the .exe properties and click unblock.
2. Have you tried install as admin (right click run as admin)
3. Tried turning off your anti virus and install?
4. Tried re downloading the application then installing again?
5. Are you installing it on another HDD and not C Drive? (try
   installing it on another HDD if possible)
6. Did you do a clean install of Windows 10 or just an upgrade?, if
   true then    delete any old files/uninstall from windows.old
   folder(think its hidden from memory)
7. Did you previously have another Visual Studio installed? Delete old
   registry keys or any traces of visual studio

Comment: Thank you Carl for your answer. I had already solved by disabling Antivirus, making sure that enough space was available and some other steps. I'm giving you an Up vote for your effort.